# OleDb / DataTable to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5, oledb

have to extract data from a mdb file on the server. I can open and access the data. Now i have to map it to a model and i have no Idea how to receive the data as a model. My idea was to loop through the received DataTabel data and assign it to values of the model type:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlcommand, DbConnection);
adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
dt = new DataTable();
try
{
   DbConnection.Open();
   adapter.Fill(dt);

   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      var examplemodel= new exampleModel(
         Id = row.ItemArray[0],
         ...
      );
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
   DbConnection.Close();
}
```

The problem here is that I can not assign row.ItemArray[x] as an element of the model since row.ItemArray[x] is of type object and I cannot convert it to a int string or whatever. 
Also I thought that there is maybe a simpler and cleaner approach to this problem. 
Any ideas or suggestion are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var Entity=(from DataRow dataRow in data.Rows select YourEntity<exampleModel>(dataRow)).ToList();
```

The Helper Class

```
 public static T YourEntity<T>(DataRow row) where T : new()
            {
                var entity = new T();
                var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    //Get the description attribute
                    var descriptionAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (descriptionAttribute == null)
                        continue;

                    property.SetValue(entity, row[descriptionAttribute.Description]);
                }

                return entity;
            }
```

and Decorate the Entity with proper datatable header

```
 public class exampleModel
{
....
[Description("Subentity_datatable_header_header")]
        public string Subentity { get; set; }
....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer simple `Linq`. Whatever approach it may be, it is very clean and safe if we use the column *names* instead of *index*.

You could do something like.

```
dt.Rows.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(r=> new exampleModel()
              {
                   Id =  r.Field<int>("col1"),
                   Name = r.Field<string>("col2"),
                   ...
              });
```

Comment: Hello Hari, i like the approach with Linq and thank you for your answer. I tried something similar but AsEnumerable is only defined for a whole dataTable and not for a selected row. Or have I missed something?

Comment: `DataTable` doesn't have `SelectedRows` property, do you mean to say filter based on some _column_ value?